# Error when post image from Android App to C# WCF Service

Tags: android, json, wcf, android-volley

**Java Method for Upload**

```
public Boolean EnviarArquivo(File arquivo) throws IOException
{
    Boolean ret = false;

    Log.d(TAG, "Eviando arquivo via http");

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URLs.UPLOAD_ARQUIVO);
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    InputStream is = null;
    byte[] buffer = null;
    is = new FileInputStream(arquivo);
    buffer = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();

    // Transformando array de bytes em String para enviar ao
    // servidor
    String imagemBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT);

    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart("image", new StringBody(imagemBase64));
    httppost.setEntity(entity);

    try
    {
        String responseString = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        Log.d(TAG, "Arquivo enviado via http");
        ret = true;
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

**C# WCF Interface**

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "uploadImagem", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Bitmap uploadImagem(Stream imagem);
```

**C# WCF Service**

```
public Bitmap uploadImagem(Stream imagem)
    {
        LogWriter.WriteLog("Imagem recebida");

        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = imagem.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                buffer = ms.ToArray();
            }

            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                mStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);
                return bm;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Eclipse LogCat**
10-15 14:24:45.138: D/UploadPhotos(14370): Eviando arquivo via http
10-15 14:24:45.198: W/System.err(14370): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-15 14:24:45.208: W/System.err(14370):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
10-15 14:24:45.208: W/System.err(14370):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
10-15 14:24:45.208: W/System.err(14370):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
10-15 14:24:45.208: W/System.err(14370):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
10-15 14:24:45.208: W/System.err(14370):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
10-15 14:24:45.208: W/System.err(14370):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-15 14:24:45.208: W/System.err(14370):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-15 14:24:45.208: W/System.err(14370):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-15 14:24:45.208: W/System.err(14370):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-15 14:24:45.208: W/System.err(14370):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
10-15 14:24:45.218: W/System.err(14370):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
10-15 14:24:45.218: W/System.err(14370):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
10-15 14:24:45.218: W/System.err(14370):    at com.prologica.papirosmart.app.UploadPhotos.EnviarArquivo(UploadPhotos.java:251)
10-15 14:24:45.218: W/System.err(14370):    at com.prologica.papirosmart.app.UploadPhotos.SendFile(UploadPhotos.java:158)
10-15 14:24:45.218: W/System.err(14370):    at com.prologica.papirosmart.app.UploadPhotos.SendFolders(UploadPhotos.java:121)
10-15 14:24:45.218: W/System.err(14370):    at com.prologica.papirosmart.app.UploadPhotos.ExecutarRotina(UploadPhotos.java:81)
10-15 14:24:45.218: W/System.err(14370):    at com.prologica.papirosmart.cliente.MainActivity.InicializeUploadFiles(MainActivity.java:128)
10-15 14:24:45.218: W/System.err(14370):    at com.prologica.papirosmart.cliente.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:479)
10-15 14:24:45.228: W/System.err(14370):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1187)
10-15 14:24:45.228: W/System.err(14370):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5326)
10-15 14:24:45.228: W/System.err(14370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
10-15 14:24:45.228: W/System.err(14370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647)
10-15 14:24:45.228: W/System.err(14370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
10-15 14:24:45.228: W/System.err(14370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
10-15 14:24:45.228: W/System.err(14370):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
10-15 14:24:45.228: W/System.err(14370):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 14:24:45.228: W/System.err(14370):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 14:24:45.228: W/System.err(14370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4954)
10-15 14:24:45.228: W/System.err(14370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 14:24:45.238: W/System.err(14370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 14:24:45.238: W/System.err(14370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
10-15 14:24:45.238: W/System.err(14370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
10-15 14:24:45.238: W/System.err(14370):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 14:24:45.258: D/dalvikvm(14370): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2929K, 32% free 7694K/11267K, paused 15ms+11ms, total 91ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're trying to do networking stuff on the main (UI) thread of the Android application. This is resulting in your exception:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

The solution is to run networking code in AsyncTask. Look at [this SO question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).